# why am getting this error?

Tags: docker, jenkins, scripting

im trying to copy jenkins-cli-wrapper.sh to a directory 
but im getting the following error.

[image: error]

my code is given below 
`

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -f -y oracle-java9-installer && \
    apt install -y default-jre curl wget git nano; \
    apt-get clean

    ENV JAVA_HOME /usr
    ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

    WORKDIR /jenkins-cli
    COPY jenkins-cli-wrapper.sh .

    ENV JENKINS_URL "localhost:8080"
    ENV PRIVATE_KEY "/ssh/id_rsa"
    VOLUME /ssh

    ENTRYPOINT ["./jenkins-cli-wrapper.sh"]
    CMD ["help"]`
```

****also when i ever i try to use "ADD" and "COPY" im getting this error in every other code****

Comment: so does the `/jenkins-cli` exist? You can run the container it has just part built by doing a `docker images` then running the lates one to see what is going on

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn is that url is correct to run jenkins